# How do I change format on ActiveX Control Option Button when selected?

Tags: excel, vba

When I select the ActiveX Control Option Button the entire border (box) becomes highlighted. Is there a way to fix this, perhaps change something in Properties, so when I select the button nothing is highlighted?

Comment: Are you in design mode?

Comment: You can set the `TakeFocusOnClick` property to False?

Comment: Is `TakeFocusOnClick ` in the ActiveX option button?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find TakeFocusOnClick

Comment: i am not in design mode

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by "select the button".
If you mean to click on it, have you tried setting the "`TakeFocusOnClick`" property to False?

[image: Take Focus On Click]

Once you've set the property, click the DesignMode button to get out of Design Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is about a "control option button" which is presumably the Option Button.  While the 'Command Button' has a TakeFocusOnClick attribute, the Option Button surprisingly does not.  Neither does the Check Box.

This property does not appear on the Properties list on the worksheet in Design Mode or on the auto-complete list in the VBA editor, even though they will both take focus on click.

NOTE: ActiveX buttons are far more flexible than the stock "form controls" that appear at the top of the 'Insert' dropdown panel.

[image]

[image]